# How to delay addition of elements to the DOM in Javascript event handler

Tags: javascript, html

I use pure JavaScript **no libraries** I am newer to client side programming and especially to JavaScript.

I have my client side window delimited to the left and right side.

At some point when user press button **completeTask** event handler is fired.

The event handler adds two HTML elements one on left side another on right side of window with delay about 3000msec.

Here is conceptual description of event handler:

```
        function completeTask() 
        {
            addSomeElemntToLeftSide(); 
            delay(3000);
            addSomeElemntToRightSide();
        }
```

The problem is that both HTML elements have been added to the DOM after event handler is executed without any delay.

Any idea what should I do to make delay between adding two elements left and then after 3000msec right?

Comment: Javascript does not have a `delay()` function. For something like this you would want to use `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript does not have a `delay()` function. For something like this you would want to use `setTimeout`, like so:

```
function completeTask() {
    addSomeElemntToLeftSide(); 
    setTimeout(addSomeElemntToRightSide, 3000);
}
```

The `addSomeElemntToRightSide` function is passed to `setTimeout`, which will run it in 3000ms (3 seconds). You could also write it like this:

```
function completeTask() {
    addSomeElemntToLeftSide(); 
    setTimeout(function () {
        addSomeElemntToRightSide();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple...

```
function completeTask() 
        {
            setTimeout(addSomeElemntToLeftSide,3000); 

            setTimeout(addSomeElemntToRightSide,3000);
        }
```

if you only want a delay between the two calls, use the setTimeout only in second call...

Comment: You are calling the functions as you pass them into `setTimeout()`...

Comment: This is incorrect. By including the ( ) after the function calls, they are called immediatley. You need to remove the ( ) so that the call to setTimeout includes the function name, not a call.

Comment: You are rigth! corrected...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setTimeout()`:

```
setTimeout(addSomeElemntToRightSide, 3000);
```

The second parameter is the time you wish to wait in milliseconds.